# When is the best time to send an email to a professor about a masters position?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, email, communication

Recently, I am looking for a master position so that I had to send emails to professors.I was wondering if you tell me when is the best time to send an email? morning or afternoon? could we send mail on weekends Saturday and Sunday?

Comment: The advantage of email is: You do not have to be there when it is delivered.  You can read it when it is convenient to you.

Comment: Be aware that emails can sometimes get lost or delayed.

Answer (score 11):

In the past, I tried to optimally-time emails in this fashion. I found that it usually turned into delaying the email and needing to spend mental bandwidth tracking and remembering to do that for part of a week (to the detriment of some other small tasks).

My recommendation at this point would be: Right now. As soon as you have time to do so. Get it off your plate and move on.

Edit: I'm aware that among millennials, it's common to have email tied into one's mobile device, and therefore interact with it and view it identically to instant messaging (e.g., I've had one younger friend express irritation at receiving work emails after 5 pm). However, I will suggest that this is not the case for academics. We're usually getting hundreds of emails per week or day, and necessarily deal with it in a batched fashion at various times of our choosing (not necessarily every day).

Answer (score 2):

Some studies have shown that you should leave your least demanding tasks for later in the day, and focus on your most pressing needs within 4 hours of waking up. However, I think a lot of academics will still end up checking their emails first thing. My own supervisor asked me to do the same, check it first thing. So while a window such as 2-3 or 4-5pm makes more sense, I still think a significant percentage of academics would check it early in the morning. So also consider 8-9am.

Although another strategy might be considering when other people would be likely to send their emails. If most academically related emails are arriving early in the morning, then your email gets lost in the heap. If you send your email at 4:00 pm or 4:30pm when things have died down a little, but still within the window of normal working hours, then you might separate yourself from the pile of emails. The only downside to this approach is that if the email is significant in its content, then sending the email at a time when most people have been worn out might not be the best bet. Refer to the last point to gauge if it makes sense.

Of course as mentioned, the biggest mistake to make would be to delay a pressing email. Send it as quickly as you can, and don't overthink it.

Lastly, you should also consider past experience (if you have any)! If 90% of your responses have come at 7pm, then why not go for 7pm? People have habits and routines, observe them.

Comment: Awesome response, I like it! It does make a lot of sense and it's also just a email at the end of the day.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume this email is important to you, therefore you should email someone within specific time-frames that are convenient for that person, of course, they'll read the email whenever they feel like it but from your perspective, if you're looking for a time that you think is going to be the best for the receiver.

I got a few tips but I can't give you the exact moment, Many people, that are very busy read their emails only in their work-time. An example they work from 8 am to 4 pm and they'll read their emails only from 2 pm till 3 pm. Now since they're reading their work-related emails only in that timeframe whenever you send it is going to be the same for that person.

This is probably an academic email (because you posted it here) therefore that person doesn't have a preference. I would say my personal opinion is after the sun goes down in your country, Muslims call it Maghrib. 
A person is relaxed but not exhausted. That's at least me.

And some people can get mad if you send them any type of message in their free-time (either they won't read(more likely) it or if they receive it they'll not be fine about it).